# Learning kanji by reading or writing entire sentences

Tags: discussion, kanji, learning

This is likely a duplicate, but I feel none of the questions I've seen on the topic of learning kanji have answered mine. Please point me in the right direction if this is not the case!

To start learning kanji is easy for me. I have access to several resources like (obviously) the internet and some apps, which allow me to search for kanji and make study guides like flashcards.

But this only teaches me the characters in very isolated instances. I can recognize the 年 kanji very quickly. Given a little bit of context I can specify the reading. But I cannot do much more than that. Simply place it in a sentence and already there's a chance my reading will slow down considerably as I attempt to place the meaning in the context of the sentence (perhaps this is too simple an example, but hopefully my point is clear). Furthermore, kanji with many different readings and varying 送り仮名 drastically slow down my reading time.

Thus I am looking for resources which will allow me to practice reading kanji in text. I seek something beyond the standard beginning kanji practice, like "translate/write in hiragana 小さい学校". This is good for starting to learn kanji, but does not go too far. I would like to learn to read "in blocks", where I spend little time reading 小さい学校 as the combination of an adjective and a noun and instead as a single term, just as when reading English I do not consider each individual word, but consider several words at once.

Books, websites, newspapers, methods where I construct my own practice, etc. are welcome. I am okay if learning takes a long time, so I do not want something which will attempt to teach me as much kanji in as little time as possible, if it means sacrificing repetition and my ability to retain kanji (not to say quick methods necessarily do this).

Bonus points for something which is organized by kanji level, so that I am only focusing on a certain subset of all characters and do not expect to see 選択公理 in the beginning. Bonus points also for something which contains unusual readings or phrases.

Comment: to address your question, I think that if you learn kanji as part of actual _words_, your reading will speed up because you will start recognising words in the sentences you come across, and you would no longer need to invest time in figuring out the correct reading and meaning for each individual character.

Comment: My apologies. I did not pay enough attention to the guidelines. Is there a way to transfer this post over to meta, or should I simply copy + paste (and delete this question)?

Comment: Hmmm I don't know if there's a way to transfer the post as it is. According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/how-do-i-move-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site), I should be able to vote for closing and move the question to another stack site, but I can't find the appropriate option in the menu. I would just create a new post there.

Comment: @jarmanso7 I will do that. Or I may use the chatroom. Thanks for your help!